# How to use TensorFlow Estimator from C++?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I'm quite new to TensorFlow,but I have to implement a TensorFlow model with C++.

I assume I can define a model (graph) with Python and export it, and call the exported graph from C++ as this article describes.

[Loading a TensorFlow graph with the C++ API](https://medium.com/jim-fleming/loading-a-tensorflow-graph-with-the-c-api-4caaff88463f)

However -- because of my limited understanding of its low layers -- I'm not sure how I can do the same with [Estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/estimators). This is because apparently there's neither "Session" nor "Graph" definition explicitly to me (I know it's wrapped inside, though).

Could you kindly instruct me here a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

Since C++ doesn't have high level apis ([reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/premade_estimators#the_programming_stack)), and tf.Session which is used inside the article is at a lower layer than Estimator's, I personally don't think this is possible.

My initial hypothesis is to use [TensorFlow Serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/) with a C++ client ([example](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_client.cc)), but any thought is very welcomed.